# How can I insert a single quote (') in sql?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I got some strings that contains a single quote (') like `Mayor's Office`:

```
Dim Str = "Insert into EntryTbl(Office, DateCreated, TimeCreated)" & _
          "Values('" & OfficeBox.Text & "', " & _
          "       '" & Now.ToShortDateString & "', " & _
          "       '" & Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") & "')"
```

and the `officebox.text` contains a string `Mayor's Office`

Glad for any help :)

Comment: Not related to your question, but storing dates and times as strings is a bad idea.  If your RDBMS supports both date and time datatypes, use them.  Otherwise use whatever the datatype is called that represents both the date and time.

Comment: You really should not be building SQL queries using strings - it's a bad practice due to SQL injection attacks. You should use a parameterized query which will automatically escape the single-quote for you.

Comment: tnx for the info..mate :)

Comment: sir @DanBracuk what do u mean by a bad idea ? does it effect in performance ? sir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMO, parametrized query is better because it prevents [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and it will handle escaping for you(*no need to write additional method to handle escaping*)

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("", Conn())
With cmd
     .CommandText = "Insert into tbl(Office, DateCreated, TimeCreated)" & _
                    "Values(@office,@DateCreated,@TimeCreated)"
     .Parameters.AddWithValue("@office", OfficeBox.Text)
     .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateCreated", Now.ToShortDateString)
     .Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeCreated", Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))
     .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

---

Take a look at [How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i) for more informations

Comment: Please note that there are some concerns with AddWithValue: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). All those links give reliable alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The built in solution is to use

```
QUOTENAME(@string)
```

function to put the quotes.

Comment: built-in ? in sql ? or vb.net ?

Comment: @yoyieyoyie, neither; its from the underlying T-SQL.